# Order of variables $f(a,b)$ vs $f(b,a)$

Tags: functions

I wanted to ask a question about the order of variables in a function.

Coming from a tutorial on mathematics for medicine, we discussed that if you had a function $f_{1}(a,b)$ and then swapped round the order $f_{1}(b,a)$ there appears to be a property that:

$$f_{1}(a,b) = -f_{1}(b,a)$$

which is especially relevant in situations involving imaginary numbers, and I was struggling to work out why.

I read a page on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) about Binary relations to try and make understanding of this, but was left hard to understand why this works.

I pondered why this really doesn't matter for when the function is a product i.e. $ab$ and this makes sense since you are only multiplying the values so the order is irrelevant e.g. $3 \times 2 \times 1$ is identical to the result of $1 \times 2 \times 3$

yet I couldn't work out why the order of variables matters, especially when related to the inner product.

I did think briefly about cartesian equations such that $f(x,y)$ is not the same as $f(y,x)$ since you are starting on the $y$ axis and ending on the $x$ axis compared to the other way round for $f(x,y)$ but that didn't give me a definitive reason for the need of a negative sign in front of the function.

Why does there have to be a change in sign when I change the order of variables?

Comment: $f(a,b)=-f(b,a)$ is a property a function *might* have, but in general doesn't. E.g., for $f(x,y):=x+2y$, this is not the case: $f(17,42)=101$ and $f(42,17)=76$.

Comment: It is definitely not true that $f(a,b)$ will have any relationship with $f(b,a)$ in general. In fact, the expression $f(b,a)$ might not even make sense mathematically. If you have a function with $f(a,b)=-f(b,a)$, then this is a special property of this particular function (or of some class of functions). But I can't really elaborate without knowing more context.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen but here is what also confuses me, is the first variable inside $f$ explicitly the $x$ value and the second variable explicitly the $y$ value? I.e. I can't switch $17$ and $42$ around if the function is a sum and get the same result? Apologies if it seems normal to you but I was wondering whether this has a specific property, a bit like in programming where if you have `my_function(x,y)` that order is specific and will alter the result if the numbers are swapped?

Comment: In my example, by the very definition of the expression to compute $f(x,y)$ as $x+2y$, I declared that the first argument shall always correspond to the $x$ in $x+2y$. Thus $f(a,b)=a+2b$, $f(\tilde \xi,\eta_7^*)=\tilde \xi+2\eta_7^*$, $f(17,42)=17+2\cdot 42)$, $f(t,t)=t+2\cdot t$, and of course $f(y,x)=y+2x$

Comment: Fantastic! Is there a specific term that describes this property? @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: One example is an alternating linear map https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_multilinear_map.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of a function of two variables as assigning a number $f(x,y)$ to each point $(x,y)$ in the plane. The graph of $f$ will be a surface - the height above $(x,y)$ is $f(x,y)$.

Swapping the coordinates of a point reflects that point over the line $y=x$. To see that, experiment with, say $(1,2)$ and $(3,3)$.

Sometimes the value of a function at the reflected point is related to the value where you started. In your particular example, it's the negative. For example, the function
$$
f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2
$$
has that property. here's a numerical check:
$$
f(2,1) = 4-1 = 3
$$
while
$$
f(1,2) = 1 - 4 = -3.
$$
The graph is above the plane when $x > y$ and below when $x < y$. The value when $x=y$ is $x^2 - y^2 = 0$.

Most functions of two variables will not behave this way. There may be some particular function in your medical application that does.

Answer (score 0):

> Coming from a tutorial on mathematics for medicine, we discussed that if you had a function f1(a,b) and then swapped round the order f1(b,a)
>
> there appears to be a property that:
>
> f1(a,b)=−f1(b,a)

I think the tutoral was taling about *one* particulare function.  This is not at all true in general.

Suppose $f(a,b) = \cos a + b^2$.

Obviously it is not true that $f(a,b) = \cos a + b^2 = -\cos b - a^2 = f(b,a)$.  Why on earth would that be true?

I suspect that they were talking about a specific function.  For example: (I'm making this up off the top of my head) lesseee....oh!  This would be the simplest!  $f(a,b) = a-b$.  Then $f(b,a) = b-a = -(a-b) = -f(a,b)$.

There are probably less trivial examples.  $f(a,b) =a^3 - 3a^2b + 3ab^2 - b^3$ for example.  $f(b,a) = b^3 - 3b^2a + 3ba^3 -a^3 =-(a^3 - 3a^2b + 3ab^2 - b^3)=-f(a,b)$